# modify included file on click

Tags: php, html, css

Here is my header.php file I included it on every page , my problem is whenever i try to destroy session it is not happening I callout a page logout.php and destroy session there but nothing happen it is again registered with same session id

### header.php

```
session_start();

 $key=md5(uniqid());
 $_SESSION['session']=session_id($key);

 $sid=$_SESSION['session'];
```

### logout.php

```
<?php  
 include("header.php"); 

session_unset();
session_destroy();
 header("Location:login.php");

    ?>
```

can i modify the header file on button click ? like destroy the session there or is there other ways to do it

ps . that is just a basic task i am doing so no security issues ATM.

Comment: Can you show us login.php as well?

Comment: remove `header.php` from login page if you include.because it set session again.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set the session variable in header.php
In your scenario, it will set session on each page where header.php is included.
Keep session set and destroy page differently.

Comment: but i need same session until I logged out or close browser . when i put it on each page it simply changes every time I refresh